# Можно ли на Wordpress использовать AMP в подгрузке постов через loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, amp

Подскажите,пожалуйста, подключил плагин для работы с AMP в среде Wordpress. И с amp версией страниц постов проблем нет. Всё что залито в админке, то и подргружается. А как поступить с главной страницей если весть контент это посты, которые подгружаются через loop. Т.е в админке главная страница пустая, поэтому amp версия так же пустая. Возможно ли как-то интегрировать подргрузку постов в AMP ?

Comment: возможно всё. максимум что Вам грозит - править шаблоны ручками.

Comment: но если руками, то нужно все руками правильно? т.е комбинировать работу плагина установленного и просто кода нельзя? Если плагин сейчас подтягивает amp к страницам постов. То получается если буду писать руками то и для них придется писать